# Transistor saturation current

Tags: transistors

[image]

From the above I/V characteristic we can conclude (and this is what books say) that during saturation collector current is very limited and tends to zero. How is that possible if during such condition there is siginificant current flowing from base to collector. So it can not be zero in any way.

Comment: Show us a book that says that.

Comment: The books I read say that saturation is when the BE junction and BC junction are both forward biased. It does not depend on collector current at all, except that you cannot forward bias both junctions without having some collector current. What that graph is telling you is that when the BC junction is reverse biased, the current does not depend on Vce. (Instead, it depends on Ib, but the graph doesn't show that).

Comment: @mkeith The way I like to express it, when asked, is that in active mode the collector-emitter is *like* a current source/sink and that in deep saturation the collector-emitter is *like* a small voltage source, instead. In between, it is transitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make notes about my assumptions before talking:

- Those unlabeled curves are specified for \$I_\text{B}\$ set to specific values. This means the base current is fixed for each curve and doesn't change.
- The value of \$V_\text{CE}\$ is the \$x\$-axis and \$I_\text{C}\$ is the \$y\$-axis.

Your question then is how to interpret what you see there.

---

How does \$V_\text{CE}\$ decline?

I suspect that you imagine there is a constant current supply used at the base and that there is also a voltage supply on the bench where someone just twiddles a knob on the voltage supply to change the voltage on \$V_\text{CE}\$, plotting the current that the voltage supply (or a meter) reports.

I suppose one could try it that way. But it doesn't help you understand what is going on nearly as well as thinking about this differently. So I'll put it to you in a different way and see if that helps, better.

Suppose that instead of varying a voltage supply tied directly across the emitter and collector, there still is that constant current supply at the base but now a fixed voltage (say \$10\:\text{V}\$) supply value is set up and there is a variable resistor used between this voltage supply and the collector. (If NPN, the emitter is grounded; or at the negative supply rail.)

The value for \$V_\text{CE}\$ is measured with a voltmeter attached appropriately, as the resistor value is varied. Assuming that \$\beta\$ is roughly fixed when in the active mode, the value of \$I_\text{C}\$ should not change as the resistor is varied. But \$V_\text{CE}\$ will vary because the resistor will drop a voltage that varies with its resistance. So this means we can still plot \$I_\text{C}\$ vs \$V_\text{CE}\$.

We expect to see:

$$V_\text{CE}=10\:\text{V} - R_\text{POT}\cdot I_\text{C}$$

But what happens when this varying resistance gets so large that the second term in the above equation, \$R_\text{POT}\cdot I_\text{C}\$, is close to \$10\:\text{V}\$? Certainly, it cannot be possible that \$V_\text{CE}\$ goes negative, right! There's no way for that to happen.

What starts to happen is that \$V_\text{CE}=10\:\text{V} - R_\text{POT}\cdot I_\text{C}\$ approaches the voltage at the base (which is probably somewhere between \$600\:\text{mV}\$ and \$900\:\text{mV}\$ for a small signal device.) As the voltage drop represented in the second term there forces \$V_\text{CE}\$ below that base voltage, the base-collector junction becomes forward-biased and starts to conduct significant current of its own, which can become quite large as the collector voltage approaches the emitter voltage very closely.

Keep in mind that we are using a current source at the base. So this newly developing base-collector forward-biased current doesn't add to the base current. It's important you hold that fact in your mind. There's a current source there, so that's just not possible to change in any way. Instead, this newly developing forward-biased base-collector current ***takes away*** from the recombination current that is required to allow collector current to flow.

The base current being supplied has now fractured into two meaningful parts: (1) \$I_{\text{F}_\text{BC}}\$, the *forward-biased BC diode current*; and, (2) \$I_{\text{F}_\text{RECOMB}}\$, the *necessary recombination current to allow collector currents to flow*.

Now \$I_\text{B}=I_{\text{F}_\text{RECOMB}}+I_{\text{F}_\text{BC}}\$, so obviously:

$$I_{\text{F}_\text{RECOMB}}=I_\text{B}-I_{\text{F}_\text{BC}}$$

Or, put another way, the newly developing forward-biased base-collector diode current *takes away from* the available recombination current that permits collector current to flow. So the collector current declines as a result.

And the larger this forward-biased base-collector diode current becomes (the larger the forward-biased base-collector voltage becomes) the deeper into ***saturation*** is the transistor as the remaining recombination current rapidly declines. "Shallow saturation" means that the forward-biased base-collector diode current is just a small portion of the total base current. "Deep saturation" means that the forward-biased base-collector diode current is a large portion of the total base current.

(This also happens if you apply that voltage supply directly across the collector and emitter, since this *also* means that there is a forward-biased base-collector diode current that is subtracting from the available base current.)

Comment: +1, you are a good teacher ;)

Comment: I think i got the picture however I am confused a bit about this: "Keep in mind that we are using a current source at the base...". How can we guarantee current source there, plus how is that possible that this forward bias BC junction doesn't curry any current? After all it should.

Comment: @DannyS (1) An adequate current source is easy to design. So that's possible to apply, without difficulty. It's an external circuit designed to do a job. (2) I spent a lot of my discussion saying exactly that the forward-biased BC junction DOES carry current! It's just that it is internal to the BJT and does NOT show up as an externally viewable current at the collector. It moves into the internal collector area but cannot be seen at the pin there.

Comment: @jonk, so are you trying to say that this "internal" collector current somehow "turn" from flowing futher into collector and instead flows to emitter?

Comment: @DannyS There is a base current that is ***fixed*** by the fact that there is an instrument making sure of it in the test setup. There is a BC junction that is usually reverse-biased (active mode.) When reverse-biased, the BC diode current is nearly zero and ***all*** of the base current is therefore ***recombination*** current -- which is what is ***needed*** for collector current to flow. No recombination current? No collector current. Simple as that.

Comment: @DannyS So, when the BC junction becomes forward-biased and starts conducting ***significant*** current (since it is no longer reverse-biased), this current cannot be used as ***recombination*** current. It ceases to be useful for that purpose. Therefore, it subtracts from the constant base current, leaving ***less*** recombination current. Lower recombination current means lower collector current.

Answer (score 1):

When the transistor saturates at the beginning of the current gain , Beta drops towards 10% of Max Beta . This is specified in the data sheet as Vce(sat)@Ic/Ib=10.  So you can see the beta has reduced to 10 at the rated saturation voltage from which we can compute the effective Rce=Vce(sat)/Ic .

Both Beta max and Ic max affect Rce which can range from 10mohms to 10 ohms for Pmax ratings of transistor from 100W to 100mW

This current of BC is when it becomes forward biased as a switch to approach BE voltage drop with a current ratio of 10 to 20 and in rare cases Vce(sat) @ Ic/Ib=50 from guys like Diodes Inc and others.